# Diskstation - Lost Backup Jobs

Tags: backup, synology

We use a diskstation as a backup destination for most of the servers on our network. Daily, these backups are sent to an external hard drive using the backup and restore tool. Drives are swapped each day.

We have two backups for user data and mail data that are working properly so far. However, I need to also add a LUN backup that has our domain controller data. I successfully created a backup and it backed up once. Then, this happens:

[image]

The LUN backup is deleted and vanishes. This happens with any LUN backup I create. Note that this is a recurring backup, so it shouldn't be getting deleted. Am I missing something?